# Angular unit test with private variable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to write the unit test for the private variable. But Jasmine is not allowing me to use it. Can someone explain me how to do it?

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  private resolve;

  public testPrivate() {
    this.resolve(false);
  }
}

 it(
      'should test private variable', () => {
        component.testPrivate();
        expect(component.resolve).toEqual(false);
 });
```

Answer (score 28):

```
 expect(component['resolve']).toEqual(false);
```

or

```
 expect((<any>component).resolve).toEqual(false);
enter code here
```

However, technically you should not be testing a Private variable simply because it's `private` member of a class and it's meant to be accessed only within the class itself, if you really wanna test it, you have to make it public or create a `getter` `setter` for it which are public.

And by the way, your test doesn't make much sense to me, unless you haven't written the whole test in here.

Cause you're calling `this.resolve(false)`, meaning that it's a function , then why are you testing it to be equal to `false` ?

EDIT :

did you mean this : ?

```
 public testPrivate() {
   this.resolve = false;
 }
```

Comment: TypeError: this.resolve is not a function. Getting this error when tried the first approach.

Comment: how are you expecting this : `private resolve;`  to be a function that you can call ?

Comment: nice solution.. brother

Comment: Can be done also like this `expect((component as any).resolve).toEqual(false);`